# Expand area of SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm new to using SVGs so I appreciate any patience with what may be a silly question.

I have an SVG image of a cake-like-shape.[image: Screenshot of Cake SVG]

Here is the code:

```
<svg version="1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 142 66" enable-background="new 0 0 142 66" xml:space="preserve">
    <linearGradient id="XMLID_115_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="2e-6" y1="42" x2="142" y2="42">
        <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#F8E8B9"/>
        <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:#E6C173"/>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#F8E8B9"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <!-- Side of Cake -->
    <path id="XMLID_1_" opacity="1" fill="url(#XMLID_115_)" d="M0,48C0,58,32,66,71,66s71-8,71-18V18
c0,10-32,18-71,18S0,27,0,18L0,48z"/>

    <g id="XMLID_5_">
        <linearGradient id="XMLID_116_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="71" y1="35" x2="71" y2="9e-13">
            <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#E6C173;stop-opacity:1"/>
            <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#F8E8B9"/>
        </linearGradient>

        <!-- Top of Cake -->
        <ellipse id="XMLID_4_" opacity="1" fill="url(#XMLID_116_)" cx="71" cy="18" rx="71" ry="18"/>

    </g>
</svg>
```

This was created and exported in Illustrator.

What I want to do is to reduce the width but not the height. It doesn't matter whether it is in JavaScript, CSS or any other method.

Effectively, the cakes will stack whilst keeping the same visual perspective.

From what I gather I just need to extend the length of the side of the cake path (labeled in comments), but am not able to find any way of doing so. It is very possible that I am way off in my guesses!

[I've done up a quick jsfiddle with the CSS from the answer below.](http://jsfiddle.net/0r97wwnu/)

Answer (score 0):

a simple way would be using `transform:scaleX()` in the CSS on the entire SVG element:

```css
//svg{transform:scaleX(0.6)}

 svg{transform:scale(0.6,0.6)}//for uniforme scaling
```

```html
<svg version="1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 142 66" enable-background="new 0 0 142 66" xml:space="preserve">
    <linearGradient id="XMLID_115_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="2e-6" y1="42" x2="142" y2="42">
        <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#F8E8B9"/>
        <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:#E6C173"/>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#F8E8B9"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <!-- Side of Cake -->
    <path id="XMLID_1_" opacity="1" fill="url(#XMLID_115_)" d="M0,48C0,58,32,66,71,66s71-8,71-18V18
c0,10-32,18-71,18S0,27,0,18L0,48z"/>

    <g id="XMLID_5_">
        <linearGradient id="XMLID_116_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="71" y1="35" x2="71" y2="9e-13">
            <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#E6C173;stop-opacity:1"/>
            <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#F8E8B9"/>
        </linearGradient>

        <!-- Top of Cake -->
        <ellipse id="XMLID_4_" opacity="1" fill="url(#XMLID_116_)" cx="71" cy="18" rx="71" ry="18"/>

    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This seems to change the angle of the curve. I will update my question now to be a little more precise.

Comment: Please see my revised question and jsfiddle. Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: @matt1985 if something is wrong with scaling horizontally , I don't understand the desired output; please be more descriptive.

Comment: scaling horizontally is good but I need it not to change the curve of the cake. When the scaled down one is placed on top of the larger one, it changes the viewing perspective because the curves have changed. You can see this in the jsfiddle

Comment: @matt1985 if you want to maintain the same height the scaling can't be uniforme. if you want uniforme scaling you can use `transform:scale(0.7,0.7)`

Answer (score 0):

hi here i tried to manage this wAy you can check

```css
.container {
    postition: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#Layer_1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
}
#Layer_2 {
    position: relative;
    transform: scaleY(0.7);
    transform: scaleX(0.7);    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg version="1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 142 66" enable-background="new 0 0 142 66" xml:space="preserve">
        <linearGradient id="XMLID_115_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="2e-6" y1="42" x2="142" y2="42">
            <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#F8E8B9"></stop>
            <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:#E6C173"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#F8E8B9"></stop>
        </linearGradient>

            <!-- Side of Cake -->
            <path id="XMLID_1_" opacity="1" fill="url(#XMLID_115_)" d="M0,48C0,58,32,66,71,66s71-8,71-18V18
    c0,10-32,18-71,18S0,27,0,18L0,48z"></path>

            <g id="XMLID_5_">
                <linearGradient id="XMLID_116_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="71" y1="35" x2="71" y2="9e-13">
                    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#E6C173;stop-opacity:1"></stop>
                    <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#F8E8B9"></stop>
                </linearGradient>

                <!-- Top of Cake -->
                <ellipse id="XMLID_4_" opacity="1" fill="url(#XMLID_116_)" cx="71" cy="18" rx="71" ry="18"></ellipse>

            </g>
    </svg>

    <svg version="1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 142 66" enable-background="new 0 0 142 66" xml:space="preserve">
        <linearGradient id="XMLID_115_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="2e-6" y1="42" x2="142" y2="42">
            <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#F8E8B9"></stop>
            <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:#E6C173"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#F8E8B9"></stop>
        </linearGradient>

            <!-- Side of Cake -->
            <path id="XMLID_1_" opacity="1" fill="url(#XMLID_115_)" d="M0,48C0,58,32,66,71,66s71-8,71-18V18
    c0,10-32,18-71,18S0,27,0,18L0,48z" style="transform: scaleY(0.7);"></path>

            <g id="XMLID_5_">
                <linearGradient id="XMLID_116_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="71" y1="35" x2="71" y2="9e-13">
                    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#E6C173;stop-opacity:1"></stop>
                    <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#F8E8B9"></stop>
                </linearGradient>

                <!-- Top of Cake -->
                <ellipse id="XMLID_4_" opacity="1" fill="url(#XMLID_116_)" cx="71" cy="18" rx="71" ry="18" style="transform: scaleY(0.8);"></ellipse>

            </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

you can check out on this **[Take a Look](http://jsfiddle.net/0r97wwnu/1/)**

Comment: Thank You. This is looking a bit better. Can you please explain what you changed?

Comment: i have changged   transform: scaleX(0.7); to   transform: scaleY(0.7);for layer2 same thing added to the XMLID_1_ id element and also to the XMLID_4_ so that it will **scale in the y position** that is  you can say vertical

Comment: @matt1985 if this helped you you can upvote this one and bdw honored to help